# Access: How to get most recent datetime of table data changes

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited a legacy Access app that has a TON of code running before the main form comes up. This code imports data, deletes data, and changes data a million ways.

Is there a way where (after the startup stuff is finished) I can list the tables and when each of them had data affected most recently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm afraid the answer to your question is simply: No.

Here's an idea though:

- Make a backup of the database file.
- Open the app so it runs the code you are concerned about.
- Compare the DB to the backup using a tool like [Red Gate SQL Data compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

BTW: I'm not sure if the RedGate tool works against access databases, but [FMSInc.](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/databasecompare.html) has one that claims to.

Comment: I would not bother with tools when all that is required is to step through the tables and fields in VBA, it is pretty quick. I regularly compare Access databases with a little code.